# How to get a Docker container started using Cloud Run to connect the Cloud Run VM network?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I am using Cloud Run and Scheduler to run a docker container periodically on GCP. I need the docker container to run a command on start up which would require default auth credentials which are found on the VM that Cloud Run/Scheduler spins up to run the Docker container and hence need the container to connect to the VM network. I have done this with Cloud Build using the `--network=cloudbuild` argument before.

However providing the same argument to Cloud Run as `--network=cloudrun` or `--network host` both lead to the same error: `could not start container: "--network/--network=cloudrun" not found in PATH [/usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin]: no such file or directory"`

I am using the Terraform google_cloud_run_v2_job resource to configure this job and using ENTRYPOINT to run the command on container start up.

Any help in aiding me in connecting to the container to the VM network would be great, thank you.

Comment: Use serverless VPC connector with Cloud RUn: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Comment: You can't reach private resource with Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: The command flag `--network` does not exist in Cloud Run. Cloud Run does not use Docker, therefore some Docker features will not work (are not supported).